# Can $A^{c} \cap B^{c} = A^{c} - (A^{c} \cap B)$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Can $A^{c} \cap B^{c} = A^{c} - (A^{c} \cap B)$? I am using this identity to prove the probabilities for $A^{c}$ and $B^{c} $ are independent, given those for $A$ and $B$ are independent.
Is there anything wrong with this identity?

Comment: Nothing wrong, it's fine. Note that $X - Y = X \cap Y^c$ is the definition of set difference, so $A^c - (A^c \cap B) = A^c \cap (A^c \cap B)^c = A^c \cap (A \cup B^c) = (A^c \cap A) \cup (A^c \cap B^c) = A^c \cap B^c$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's calculate, and see if we can start from the most complex side and simplify, using the definitions and logic.

For any $\;x\;$,
\begin{align}
& x \in A^c - (A^c \cap B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definitions of $\;-\;$, $\;\cap\;$, and $\;^c\;$"} \\
& x \not\in A \land \lnot (x \not\in A \land x \in B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: use $\;x \not\in A\;$ on other side of $\;\land\;$"} \\
& x \not\in A \land \lnot (\text{true} \land x \in B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& x \not\in A \land x \not\in B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"reintroduce $\;^c\;$ (twice) and $\;\cap\;$ using their definitions"} \\
& x \in A^c \cap B^c \\
\end{align}
So by set extensionality ("equal sets have the same elements"), $\;A^c - (A^c \cap B) = A^c \cap B^c\;$.